# What does the error "1:1Typechecker Internal Error: User type in value position" mean?

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

I was going through the [Rotatable Wallet](https://docs.kadena.io/learn-pact/beginner/rotatable-wallet) tutorial on the Kadena beginner tutorial, and I ran into this error: "1:1Typechecker Internal Error: User type in value position". What does this mean? And where exactly is the error occurring?

Comment: Please include the minimal steps you took to get that error. Make sure someone else can reproduce your result